# Magmi import images with different file extension

Tags: image, file, magento, import, magmi

I am using Magmi to import products into Magento.

I upload all images to local folder (media/import) where files are either .jpg or .gif.

Images are named:

```
[sku.jpg] OR [sku.gif]
```

I have now configured Magmi so it imports all jpg images and this works fine.

This is how my CSV looks (only image columns):

```
image,small_image,thumbnail
sku,sku,sku
```

I am then using "value replacer" plugin to insert .jpg behind every sku in image columns. This also works fine.
[image]

Is it possible to also search for .gif in same import, so it either finds a sku with file extension .jpg or .gif ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but I'm sure you'd be able to do something like this:

```
+{{ (file_exists({item.sku} . '.gif') ? {item.sku} . '.gif' : {item.sku} . '.jpg') }}
```

I don't know the full location of the images, so it might need tweaking a bit, but the idea behind it should be correct.

Comment: I tried but i get this error: "SKU testsku- Image attributes processor v1.0.33 - testsku.jpg cannot be found in images path" if only a gif image is in image folder.

Comment: Like I said, you may need to tweak the part in the file_exists() call so that it looks in the correct directory.

Comment: The gif file is in same directory as the jpg file. Only 2 image files in folder, just renamed the jpg to see if it works.

Comment: Well the only way it would try and use the .jpg is if the .gif doesn't exist. So you'll need to start your search from there.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? What you need to do is make sure that the `file_exists({item.sku} . '.gif')` points to the correct directory e.g.  `file_exists('/media/import/' . {item.sku} . '.gif')`.

Comment: I finally got it working with your solution. I needed to add absolute path. Working solution is like this: +{{ (file_exists('/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/media/import/' . {item.sku} . '.gif') ? {item.sku} . '.gif' : {item.sku} . '.jpg') }}

Comment: How can I import products images for multi-store, may i know csv header columns